# Is there any hard cut rule that all the tables in the data model should have a join condition to fact table

Tags: data-modeling, calculated-columns, hana

I'm working on building a data model/calculated view on SAP HANA DB. And I was in need of a dummy table which is not linked to the fact table. When I run the model, it started throwing an error that there is an issue with the logical table join. 
I had used the dummy table to switch between current value and historical value of a measure

Comment: It sounds like in SAP HANA there is.

Comment: What do you mean by “switch” between historical and current measure values? Do you mean filter records based on a date?

Comment: "switch" does help in converting the base currency to either the exchange rate of past quarter or to the current quarter